# Code Signing issue for Project with Multiple Targets

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, code-signing

I'm trying to get my application, which does not appear in the Dock, to have an option to launch at login. This is tricky, and involves creating a second, helper application which you add as a startup item. This helper app is only responsible for launching the main app and then exiting.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://blog.mcohen.me/2012/01/12/login-items-in-the-sandbox/) and  [here](http://www.delitestudio.com/2011/10/25/start-dockless-apps-at-login-with-app-sandbox-enabled/) and it works like a charm - the problem is, of course, code signing. I have two targets; the helper app target is copied to the `Contents/Library/LoginItems` subdirectory of the main bundle at compile time. Each bundle has its own bundle identifier and own deployment provisioning profile, but when I validate my archive for the app store, I get the following error:

```
Invalid provisioning profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle BUNDLE NAME [BUNDLE NAME.app] is invalid. For more information, visit the Mac OS Developer Portal.
```

If I remove the helper bundle from my main target, there's no problem. It looks like the presence of another provisioning profile is setting off the error.

How can I include two signed bundles and pass the validation?

Comment: I have the exact same problem...

Comment: For now, I've disabled sandboxing. It's a very temporary "solution" that will only work until Apple either fixes Xcode or stops pushing back the sandboxing deadline.

Comment: This does not solve the issue for me, I still don't pass validation if I disable entitlements, I will pass only if I remove the helper app itself...

Comment: Really? I honestly didn't try to use the helper app at all, since without sandboxing, I could switch back to the older, non-sandboxed APIs. I was able to use [this](https://github.com/pkamb/OpenAtLogin) repo out of the box for my project.

Comment: Yeah, so I deleted the helper app, changed startup item creation to the old way, removed sandboxing and successfully submitted to the app store...

Comment: @AshFurrow This might sound silly, but why do you need two separate provisioning profiles? Meaning, have you tried using the same profile for both apps - that would rule out an invalid profile and indicate something else is going wrong... Is there a specific need for it? (I might simply not be up to speed on this topic, so please bear with me.)

Comment: Not a bad question - I need the helper application to have a bundle identifier distinct from my main application, and each profile is bound to a single bundle identifier.

Comment: @AshFurrow Got it... alright. Sorry, then, no idea. Not enough experience with the app store and provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this problem by using `codesign` on a coworker's computer (there must have been something wrong with my Keychain) and deleting the `embedded.provisionprofile` file from the helper app by adding the following run script:

```
if [ -f "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile" ];
then
    rm "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile"
    echo "Removed embedded provisioning profile."
else
    echo "No profile found"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the same Mac App Store Production Certificate to sign both the helper app and the main application. I haven't tried this in Xcode — we have a helper app that's a bundle resource, but our code signing is a command line script. We didn't have any problems with the app store system.

I'm not sure why you're ending up with a provisioning profile in the built product, and I don't think this is required for app store submission. You can try using `codesign` manually:

```
codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company" \
    -i "com.mycompany.loginitem" \
    --entitlements path/to/loginitem.entitlements" \
    path/to/appname.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/loginitem.app

codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company" \
    -i "com.mycompany.appname" \
    --entitlements path/to/app.entitlements" \
    path/to/appname.app
```

Comment: Two issues: if I look in the bundle, I do in fact see a file `embedded.provisionprofile`, and if I try to use `codesign`, I get the following error: `object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable`. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I don't think I've seen that error. Are you signing a `.app` bundle or is it just an executable? I remember having problems when trying to sign an executable directly, but it seems even that works fine for me. The profile shouldn't be needed (at least we haven't had any issues with that) -- what happens if you remove it and try signing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Instead of removing embedded.provisionprofile from the helper app I've just disabled provisioning (Provision profile: None) leaving code signing identify and entitlements in place. Submitted my app for review without any issues.