# How do you exclude your provisioning profile from an XPC service?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, code-signing, mac-app-store

I'm got a Mac App Store app for I'm trying to submit a minor bug fix release. This is my first Xcode 6 release, though, which is causing problems suddenly with a configuration that worked in the past.

I'm able to submit to Apple, but I then get rejected with an "invalid binary" status and the following in an email:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyAppName". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> **Invalid Provisioning Profile Location** - The provisioning profile for your Mac OS X app must be located in the Contents directory of the main app bundle. A provisioning profile is optional, but you cannot submit more than one.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

I don't care whether my app includes a provisioning profile or not, since I don't use in-app purchase or any other App Store features that require one (yet). I only include it because Xcode configures the project that way. It assigns the `XC: *` provisioning profile (which I didn't create) for the main bundle, and the XPC service, which you can see when I go to submit:

[image: App submission confirmation screen]

In the Code Signing section of my project, I specify **Automatic** as the Provisioning Profile setting, and this is not overridden in any target (including my QuickLook plugin). Both the main bundle and the XPC service specify an entitlements file, which is required.

The only other options for Provisioning Profile are the **Mac Team Provisioning Profile** profiles Xcode creates automatically, which are for development, not distribution, and **Other**, which takes free-form text. But **Other** must specify a valid provisioning profile name, or else the build fails. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19947805/105717), there used to be a **None** option, which must have been removed in Xcode 6?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528803/mac-app-has-embedded-provisioning-profile), but the only answer suggests not signing the helper application. For an XPC service, that isn't an option. Or is it? I have "Code Sign On Copy" checked for it in the "Copy XPC Service" build phase of my main app bundle (a new Xcode 6 option).

How can I stop the provisioning profile from being included in my XPC service's bundle?

Comment: Any reason you can't use Xcode 5 to deploy your app until this bug in 6.0.1 is fixed?

Comment: @Elwisz Where can I download it from? I didn't see it on the Apple dev page. Also, I didn't want to assume I was doing everything right, either.

Comment: You can download Xcode 5.1.1 (which I can confirm isn't affected by this bug) from https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1/xcode_5.1.1.dmg

Comment: @Elwisz Awesome, thanks. I'll give it a shot. I guess I was also concerned about downgrading, after upgrading all the command line tools, also. I'll report back if that causes any issues.

Comment: No need to worry, you can have different versions of Xcode in parallel. Just rename your downloaded Xcode.app to Xcode5.app or similar before moving it into your Applications folder.